# Draw a PostgreSQL geometry in a PDF file with PHP

Tags: pdf, php

Is there a way to draw a PostgreSQL geometry in a PDF file using a PHP script?

Answer (score 1):

Commercial solution is use FME to export data to 3d PDF, this one supports vector data.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can execute Gdal and ImageMagick from any language.

```
gdal_rasterize -b 1 -i -burn -9999 PG:'host=localhost dbname='unep''
               -sql "SELECT ST_buffer(the_geom, .12) 
                     from coastlines where name='Poland'" Poland_elev.tif
```

ImageMagick will convert a tiff to a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I use a php framework (CodeIgniter) in my apps which has a pdf library plugin to create the pdf document. Then I generate a url that calls my Mapserver WMS to get a map image of the appropriate size, features and use that url as an image tag (like: img src="url" ) in the pdf doc. It's a rather complicated solution, but it shows that it can be done and works well now.